# "electron-forge" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: cmd, windows-10, electron, norton

I was working lately with electron-forge and I had no problem, after I installed Norton I cannot use electron-forge anymore (with the Windows CMD) and I get the message: "electron-forge" is not recognized as an internal or external command. Can someone please help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comman)

Answer (score 4):

> Sorry I can't comment yet :(

Did you install  electron-forge with the `-g` attribute?

Comment: Yes! I installed it with the -g attribute

Answer (score 2):

simply used:-

```
npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli
npx electron-forge import
npm run make
```

[for more info.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start#package-and-distribute-your-application)

Answer (score 1):

I already solved the problem, I just had to add to the "path" environment variable the .bin folder inside node_modules folder.